# How to read content from reCAPTCHA protected site

Tags: recaptcha

My client needs data scraped from a website. I am planning to use php_curl. The problem is, the site is using Google reCAPTCHA. Few powerful data items are visible only when you click "show this information link". then the reCAPTCHA appears in lightbox and vanishes, and information is displayed.

I have checked the source html, the protected item is actually loaded when someone clicks, and there is no way for me to automate this click. I have even tried to open the site in iframe and then use JS to click it, but it fails as both domains are different. I have also tried to use Selenium stand alone version but its downloads are corrupt.

Comment: reCAPTCHA is designed to prevent what you're doing.

Comment: That's so true...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: alright. Thanks for guiding me. I will try to stick to these rules. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same problem but resolved it using clear my cookies in httprequest in useragent after clear cookie wait time function (tread sleep) for some time and then start scrapping again. But I am doing this in C#, not in PHP. Applying this logic may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a design flaw with the website, the reCAPTCHA will prevent you from scraping the material without human intervention.

Technically, your best bet is to employ humans to solve CAPTCHAs all day and write some software to automatically scrape the material it protects for each one they solve. A number of viable businesses have been created this way, where the data is valuable and there is a genuine public interest in opening the data-set. (For example I heard that flight companies use CAPTCHA devices to prevent price comparison sites from driving down the cost to the consumer, and I'd argue in such a case there is an overwhelming public interest to defeating such defences).

Morally, however, you would need to tell us what you are doing in order for us to advise you. It is possible your client is merely planning to steal other people's material and then attempt to monetise it for him/herself, even though they had no hand in creating it. That may breach some copyright laws, but moreover, they (and you) need to decide if the scraping is fair.